# Split a string based on the occurrence of a number after a letter

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have a string as shown below
`String = "002 - Apple043 - Ball050 - Cat".`

I need to split this and add this to a list as shown below.

`('002 - Apple','043 - Ball','050 - Cat')`

Can someone please help me with the regex expression or java code for this.

Comment: is this for java or javascript?  you have them both tagged but they are completely different languages

Comment: +1 on if this needs to be achieved in Java or Javascript. 
Otherwise code to solve this problem might not be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try java split with `(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD8mM1/1)

Comment: This won't work in JS unless you are using Chrome or the latest Edge browser.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, do the browsers that do not support lookbehinds support lookaheads? If they do perhaps one could retrieve matches rather than split, with `\d.*?[a-z](?=\d)` [ref](https://regex101.com/r/1X0Gp6/1/). Or perhaps just `.*?[a-z](?=\d)`.

Comment: Thanks @Edward. This worked

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for JavaScript code, this might help:

```js
let text = "002 - Apple043 - Ball050 - Cat";
let items = text.split(/(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])/);
console.log(items);
```

Comment: Not working in Friefox.

Comment: thanks @Leandro. I was looking more for a java code. I tried with the same regex expression in Java but it does not work.